# Conway's Game of Life Advancing the Grid (Not Same as the Last One!)

Tags: python, conways-game-of-life

Problem/Question: the grid is not getting advanced is it getting printed twice, when I only want it to be printed once. Also, this is homework and it is due ASAP, although late work is accepted for less credit in my class.

I am making Conway's game of life with these six functions:

Function 1: create a blank grid
input: nothing
return: a blank grid

Function 2: print a given grid
input: a grid
return: nothing

Function 3: load a pattern
input: a file name, a grid
return: nothing

Function 4: advance a grid one generation
input: a grid
return: a new grid advanced by one generation

Function 5: advance a cell one generation
input: a row, a column, a grid
return: whether the cell is alive or not (True or False)

Function 6: determine the number of living neighbors of a cell
input: a row, a column, a grid
return: the number of living neighbors of the cell

So far, I have made 1, 2, 3, 5, and 6, and have tried function 4. When I try to use it however I don't get an error, but actually, something that I believe is worse: simply the wrong output.

Here is a condensed version of my code so far:

```
living_cell = "O"
dead_cell = "-"


def create_blank_grid():


    line = []
    for i in range(60):
        line.append(dead_cell)
        
    grid = []
    for j in range(30):
        grid.append(line[:])
    
     return grid


# print(create_blank_grid())

def print_grid(grid):
  for i in grid:
      for j in i:
        print(j, end="")
      print()
   
  return grid


# print_grid(create_blank_grid())


def load_design(file_name, grid):
    myFile = open(file_name, "r")
    coordinates = []
    for line in myFile:
        real_line = line.split()
        row, col = real_line[0], real_line[1]
        coordinates.append((row, col))
    myFile.close()

    # turn on certain cells here

    for row, col in coordinates:
        row, col = int(row), int(col)
        # print(row, col)
        grid[row][col] = living_cell
        # print_grid(grid)


            
    return print_grid(grid)
    

# load_design("square.in", create_blank_grid())
# square just has coordinates in it like "12 35" on each line




def num_living_neighbors(row, col, grid):
    # just to make sure
    row = int(row)
    col = int(col)
    
    living_neighbors_count = 0

    if (col + 1) < len(grid[row]) and grid[row][col + 1] == living_cell:
      living_neighbors_count += 1
      
    if (col - 1) >= 0 and grid[row][col - 1] == living_cell:
      living_neighbors_count += 1

    if (row + 1) < len(grid) and grid[row + 1][col] == living_cell:
        living_neighbors_count += 1

    if (row - 1) >= 0 and grid[row - 1][col] == living_cell:
        living_neighbors_count += 1

    if (((col + 1) < len(grid[row])) and (row + 1) < len(grid)) and grid[row + 1][col + 1] == living_cell:
        living_neighbors_count += 1

    if (((row + 1) < len(grid)) and (col - 1) >= 0) and grid[row + 1][col - 1] == living_cell:
        living_neighbors_count += 1

    if (((row - 1) >= 0) and (col + 1) < len(grid[row])) and grid[row - 1][col + 1] == living_cell:
        living_neighbors_count += 1

    if (((row - 1) >= 0) and (col - 1) >= 0) and grid[row - 1][col - 1] == living_cell:
        living_neighbors_count += 1
    


    return living_neighbors_count





def adv_cell_one_gen(row, col, grid):

    
    # is alive, less than 2 alive neighbors
    if grid[row][col] == living_cell and num_living_neighbors(row, col, grid) < 2:
        return False

    # is alive, 2 or 3 alive neighbors
    if grid[row][col] == living_cell and (num_living_neighbors(row, col, grid) == 2 or num_living_neighbors(row, col, grid) == 3)
        return True

    # is alive, more than 4 alive neighbors
    if grid[row][col] == living_cell and num_living_neighbors(row, col, grid) > 3:
        return False
    # is dead, has 3 alive neighbors
    if grid[row][col] == dead_cell and num_living_neighbors(row, col, grid) == 3:
        return True

    
    
    

def adv_grid_one_gen(grid):
    
    for i in range(len(grid)):
      for j in range(i):
        adv_cell_one_gen(i, j, grid)

                
                
    return print_grid(grid)



adv_grid_one_gen(load_design("f-pentomino.in", create_blank_grid()))
```

My question is, when I called adv_grid_one_gen in te last line, I get an out put where 2 mistakes are made: 1. the printed grid is not advanced at all, and 2. the console shows that it got printed twice.

**So overall, a grid that is not advanced is getting printed twice, when I only want it to be printed once**

If anyone could offer any help, or just comment something I am doing wrong, I would appreciate it fully, but my main question is above. Thanks a lot! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Also, if you see this question and there is anything wrong with it, please leave a comment and tell me!

Comment: You're both returning and printing `grid`. See:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-return-statement

Comment: @c2huc2hu I have a new problem: the grid now updates 1 gen, but I figure out how to make it constantly update. Can you help?

Comment: Use a loop: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: @c2huc2hu I know that I should use a loop, and I have tried this many times without success. Could you help me implement this?

Comment: For anyone who wants to know, this is homework and is due soon, although any help after the deadline would be appreciated since I will still get credit for late work. To reiterate, I essentially need help ASAP.